# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{e^n n!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit to find:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^n}{e^n n!}$$

and I am given the next $5$ possible answers:

**A.** $0$

**B.** $1$

**C.** $e$

**D.** $\sqrt{e}$

**E.** $\infty$

I tried using the well-known limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n!}{n^n}$ to somehow arrive at my desired limit, but I got nowhere. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sterling approximation when $n$ is very large $$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
From here it follows that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^n}{e^n~n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}=0.$$

Comment: Your second limit should have $n\to\infty$

Comment: Correct, but a slight overkill here.

Answer (score 2):

> **I thought it would be instructive to present a way forward that does not rely on Stirling's Formula.  Rather, we proceed using only elementary analysis that includes Riemann Sums.**

With that we first note that

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}\right)&=n\log(n)-n-\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k)\\\\
&=-n\left(1+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, inasmuch as $\log(k/n)<0$, is monotonically increasing in $k$, and $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)=-1$ (Riemann Sum of $\int_0^1 \log(x)\,dx$), we can assert that $\left(1+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k/n)\right)>0$.

Hence, $\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}<1$.  The only choice that is less than $1$ is $(A) 0$.  And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) implies that $n!\sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}n^ne^{-n}$ whence
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^n}{e^n n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{e^n\sqrt{2 \pi n}n^ne^{-n}}=0
$$

Comment: Correct, but a slight overkill here.